# ssh password less connection is not working from abc@server1 to xyz@server2

Tags: ssh, solaris

ssh password less connection is not working from abc@server1 to xyz@server2 , i generated keys with RSA and copied `id_rsa.pub` from server1 to server2. still its not working

Generated keys with below

```
cd 
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
ssh-keygen -t rsa1 
ssh-keygen -t dsa 

scp id_rsa.pub xyz@server2 :/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then trying to do `ssh` from `server1` as `abc` user to

```
xyz@server2
```

Its still asking pwd

------ to server3 its working  -------------

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:RuHlMx/4SvyHbc6If32cdbAzW8p1ogG1zvIGYxULr3E /qcm/svprd/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server3 ([172.10.10.10]:22).
```

------ to server2 not working-------------

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more informationNo Kerberos credentials available
```

Comment: Please provide detail of how you copied the public key across. You can’t just SCP the file over and expect. It to work, for instance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe exactly how you set up the key, what ssh command you're running, and what happens when you run it. Please include the exact error messages that you're getting.

Comment: Cd 
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
ssh-keygen -t dsa 
cd .ssh

Comment: generated keys using Cd 
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
ssh-keygen -t rsa1 
ssh-keygen -t dsa

Comment: Please try to copy public key using `ssh-copy-id` command not scp

Comment: Its solaris 11 and ssh-copy-id is not working, can you please give me the full command

Comment: is blank between server2 and :/.ssh a typo ?

Comment: yes, can you please help me to resolve

Comment: Given `scp id_rsa.pub xyz@server2 :/.ssh/authorized_keys` and assuming it's supposed to be `scp id_rsa.pub xyz@server2:/.ssh/authorized_keys`, that puts the `.ssh` directory into the **root directory of the server**.  Are you trying to do `ssh` as `root`, **and** assumed that the `root` home directory is `/` and not something like `/root`?

Comment: I tried below command ------cat id_rsa.pub | ssh xyz@server2 'cat >> /home/xyz/.ssh/authorized_keys' --- Still its asking for password

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ssh-copy-id, correct `scp` command is

```
scp id_rsa.pub xyz@server2:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

providing

- `.ssh` exists in xyz's HOME dir on server2
- `.ssh` is 700 (`drwx------`) (`chmod u+rwx,go-rwx .ssh`)
- `authorized_keys` is 600 (`chmod 600 authorized_keys`)

Comment: performed all the above steps, its still asking password

Comment: Can anyone please help, its critical ans we need it to be worked

Comment: I could able to fix after changing $HOME permissions to 755